Should I capitalize "for" in a name?
I am writing a short story. In it, I have a character with the name

Julie Living For Soccer.

That is her actual name.
In this case, should I capitalize for or not?

You have to chosen to name your character in a manner that violates  English person-naming conventions. So you could write "for" upside down if you like.

All orthographic (ie bounded-by-open-space/s=) words and initials in names (as opposed to say book/article titles) are almost always capitalised.  Sometimes, even the elements of stacked hyphenations ('He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named''). But e e cummings probably signed his checks using lower case ... and the bank manager probably has more right than most to decide on acceptability hereabouts.

@EdwinAshworth: William of Ockham, Walter de la Mare, John von Neumann. It's perfectly fine to use lower-case for prepositions in names (and also perfectly fine to capitalize them). So it's really up to the OP.

@Peter Shaw Yes, I should have mentioned that departure.  'So it's really up to the OP' seemed to make 'open to opinion' a relevant close-vote; I use it for << the answer is 'open to opinion' >> in obvious (at this level) cases, as well as << 'the answer is open to opinion' >>.

As others say, if you're making up naming styles, you also get to make up the way they're written. You're the language God in this fictional world.

@PeterShor, of, de, and von in these names are well established ways of expressing the relationship between the two parts of the name. It is possible to think of them as belonging to neither of the two parts, which then arguably justifies the lowercase. That is different from For in the OP's case: Julie Living is not detachable from the full four-word name in the way in which William, Walter and John in your examples are.

@jsw29: On the other hand, I can't think of any real-world examples of this kind of name, so I would say that the author can capitalize it any way they want.

She Who Must Be Obeyed. It's a meaningless question though.
